# WD Velociraptor or Hybrid Drive (Seagate Momentus XT) for VMs, backups, storage?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I am looking to buy a second HDD for my laptop (I have two hdd bays). I already have a 256GB SSD, but that's not enough for Virtual Machines and incremental backups and general storage. I might also install Windows 8 for testing purposes on the second HDD, so I am looking for 500GB-750GB

So I am wondering which will be faster/better choice in such a scenario - a WD Velociraptor or a Seagate Momentus XT hybrid drive?

Comment: Shopping advice is Off Topic on Super User. [Why it is so.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say go for the Velociraptor. The Momentus XT's strength is in small, random reads thanks to the NAND read cache, which makes it a good choice for a boot drive since it can cache frequently used OS and program files. For the purposes you described, however, the cache is useless as virtual drives and backup images are way too big to fit in it. Without the bonus from the cache, the Velociraptor should be the better performer of the two, and thus the better choice.

Of course, the Momentus XT is cheaper for the same capacity, so the choice also depends on your budget. And the hybrid drive is by no means a bad choice, especially considering that for VMs you get a decent performance boost simply by having them on a separate drive from the host OS.